# Thrust access vector elements by another vector

Tags: c++, vector, cuda, thrust

In `Thrust` I have three device vectors

```
device_vector<int> ID(N)
device_vector<float> F(M),Y(N)
```

where usually `M<<N` (but that should not matter). All values of `ID` are in the range `0...M-1`.

I would now like to assign  `Y[i] = F[ID[i]]` for all `i=0...N-1`. If I understood Thrust correctly, I can't do that with `for_each` and some functor. Is there some way to implement this in a way I can make use of `thrust::transform` or something similar?

Comment: So you want nothing done on the host ?

Comment: Exactly, if possible I want to avoid the host.

Comment: This is called a "gather" operation -- take a look at the `thrust::gather` algorithm.

Comment: So:  `thrust::gather(F.begin(),F.end(),ID.begin(),Y.begin());` would be appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [`thrust:gather`](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__gathering.html), something like:

```
device_vector<int> ID(N);
device_vector<float> F(M),Y(N);

thrust::gather(ID.begin(), ID.end(), F.begin(), Y.begin());
```

In the call, `ID` is the map used to gather the values in `F` and write them into `Y`.

[standard disclaimer: written in browser, not tested, use at own risk]